# Joining data of two record types

Tags: ballerina

The code combines data from two Ballerina [table](https://ballerina.io/learn/distinctive-language-features/data/#table-concept) data structures.

The program prints the following expected and correct results (edited for readability):

```
[
  {"fooId":1,"barId":2,"data":"foo 1;bar 2"},
  {"fooId":1,"barId":4,"data":"foo 1;bar 4"},
  {"fooId":3,"barId":4,"data":"foo 3;bar 4"},
  {"fooId":3,"barId":6,"data":"foo 3;bar 6"},
  {"fooId":5,"barId":6,"data":"foo 5;bar 6"}
]
```

However I'm looking here other ways to implement/improve the data join as I feel this way is a rather clumsy (3 foreach loops and 1 query expression). I had several failed attempts to use a single [query expression](https://ballerina.io/learn/distinctive-language-features/data/#query-expressions) that IMO is the idiomatic Ballerina way.

Note that answers that modify the record definitions can not be accepted. I'm aware of an option to refactor the relationships to an [associative (or junction) table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) as I would do in the database but unfortunately, it's not an option in this case (the record definitions can't be changed).

This is Ballerina 2201.2.0 (Swan Lake Update 2)

```
import ballerina/io;

// the record definitions can't be changed

type Foo record {|
    readonly int id;
    string data;
    int[] barIds;
|};
type FooTable table<Foo> key(id);

type Bar record {|
    readonly int id;
    string data;
|};
type BarTable table<Bar> key(id);

public function main() {
    FooTable foos = table [
        {id: 1, data: "foo 1", barIds: [2, 4]},
        {id: 3, data: "foo 3", barIds: [4, 6]},
        {id: 5, data: "foo 5", barIds: [6]}
    ];

    BarTable bars = table [
        {id: 2, data: "bar 2"},
        {id: 4, data: "bar 4"},
        {id: 6, data: "bar 6"}
    ];

    table<record {|int fooId; int barId; string data;|}> fooBars = table [];

    // the code below can be changed

    foreach var foo in foos {
        table <record {|int id;|}> barIds = table [];
        foreach var barId in foo.barIds {
            barIds.add({id: barId});
        }

        var temps =
            from var barId in barIds
            join var bar in bars on barId.id equals bar.id
            select {
                fooId: foo.id,
                barId: barId.id,
                data: string`${foo.data};${bar.data}`
            }
        ;

        foreach var temp in temps {
            fooBars.add(temp);
        }   
    }

    io:println(fooBars);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the combining part like this:

```
table<record {|int fooId; int barId; string data;|}> fooBars2 = table key(fooId, barId) from var foo in foos
    from var barId in foo.barIds
    where bars.hasKey(barId)
    let Bar bar = bars.get(barId)
    select {
        fooId: foo.id,
        barId: barId,
        data: foo.data + ";" + bar.data
    };
```

Here we use nested `from` clauses where the inner from clause will iterate over the `barIds` in a `Foo` record.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation (from Ballerina Discord):

```
fooBars =
  from Bar bar in bars
  from Foo foo in foos where foo.barIds.indexOf(bar.id) != ()
  select {
    fooId: foo.id,
    barId: bar.id,
    data: string`${foo.data};${bar.data}`
};
```